# Dollars and cents java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to calculate dollars and cents on output but i dont now how to do it like the example I can only calculate all the money

Then they enter how many quarters, cents, niquel,etc, they have then i use this to have quantityTotalDollar = (int) quantityTotal % 100; to calculate the money and cents but i dont know how to calculate only coins and display it like this

You have 1 dollar(s) and 26 cent(s).

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. Also post what you already have and a rewording of the question preferably

Comment: i need to output this "You have 1 dollar(s) and 26 cent(s)." and i dont know how to do it

Comment: ok that is your output but what is your input?

Comment: i enter all the coins that the client want im using scanner, so the total on coins i want it on dollars and cents like this  "You have dollar(s) and  cent(s)" on the output

Comment: so they are entering the total number of cents or they post like 5 coins of 0.2 value, 4 coins of X value?

Comment: they are entering the total number of cents , and each coin have the constant and his value, alla the program do his add all the coins and the result need to be in dollars and cents but only show it like $1.11 and i want it like  you have dollar(s) and 26 cent(s)

Answer (score 1):

ok I think I understand now: you are given X cents and want to find out how many dollars and cents there are.

Let's say

```
int totalCoins = 234;

int dollars =  totalCoins/100;
int cents = totalCoins - (dollars*100);

System.out.println("you have $ "+dollars + " and " + cents +" cents ");
```

Here we create the "int" variable dollars which can only be whole numbers. In this case this is rounded to 2.

Then we create cents by taking the total number : 234 then taking away (2*100) which leaves 34.

Comment: You could add some explanation of _why_ this works to make it a much better answer.

Comment: @JimGarrison added some clarification.

Comment: double QUARTER= 0.25;  
double VELLON = 0.10; 
double NIQUEL = 0.05;  
double CENT = 0.01;

then they enter how many quarters, cents, niquel,etc they have then i use this to have quantityTotalDollar = (int) quantityTotal % 100; and that give me how many money i have but i dont know how to make the coins apart

Comment: @Walde add it to the main question so you can format etc.

Comment: I need to calculate dollars and cents on output but i dont now how to do it like the example I can only calculate all the money 

double QUARTER= 0.25; 
double VELLON = 0.10; 
double NIQUEL = 0.05; 
double CENT = 0.01; 

Then they enter how many quarters, cents, niquel,etc, they have then i use this to have quantityTotalDollar = (int) quantityTotal % 100; to calculate the money and cents but i dont know how to calculate only coins and display it like this 

 
You have 1 dollar(s) and 26 cent(s).

Answer (score -1):

To calculate the number of dollars + the number of cents, use this expression

```
money = (dollars) + (cents/100);
```

I assume that you want to **divide** dollars by cents though, so the following should work.

```
money = (dollars) / (cents/100);
```

I do not completely understand the question, so just remember, 1 dollar = 100 cents.